# Rails: Is there a way to disable friendly ID in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

Is there a way to disable friendly ID in development mode?

Thank's!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check rails environment in model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  unless Rails.env.development?
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  end

end
```

to skip generating new slug in development

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    false if Rails.env.development?
  end

end
```

Comment: That's a good idea. Any suggestion to only suppress the url rewriting (leaving the creation of slugs operational)? Also couldn't we do this in the gem instead of in every model?

Comment: Yes, you can skip generating new slug, i updated the code. Editing gem is not a good idea but you can override gem methods either in model or initializer.

Comment: What I want to skip is the url update. I would like to keep it using id's in dev, as it is easier to debug. Also, is there a way to put this kind of method out of the models? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this from your Gemfile:

```
gem 'friendly_id'
```

and add this on your Gemfile:

```
group :production, :test do
gem 'friendly_id'
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as it will try to load a class that doesn't exist.